# What is my vocal range (how many octaves) and how can I expand it without straining?

Tags: voice

I'm 13 years old and want to become a singer. My highest note is a D7 which I hit twice but otherwise it's an F6. My lowest is a G3. I can't really find how many octaves that is so... yeah. I'm also really unsatisfied with how high I can go, and sure a D7 is high but I haven't hit that note for 2 weeks now. So can anyone please tell me how I can possibly expand my vocal range and can someone also tell me how many octaves is G3-F6/D7?

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of the above question.  I am aware that two questions were asked here, but questions should be asked one per post on this site, and the first question is a counting problem- is the issue that you don't know what an octave is?  Maybe you don't know what "G3" actually means?  Maybe you don't know how to count part of an octave?

Comment: Please do not try to do anything to increase your range yet. Your voice is still developing, be gentle with it.  Or, carry on, and have no particularly good singing voice for the foreseeable future. To check octaves, compare with a piano - all the notes are set out there for you. And, it's not only the highest/lowest notes that count, it's the *quality* of the voice between that's more important.

Comment: @Edward - at 13yo, should OP even be considering this?

Comment: Really you need a teacher, to avoid damaging your voice. At 13 your voice is going to be changing, for the next 8 - 10 years before it settles into its adult register.